# From a given list (e.g. [2,4]), I want to get [ [1,2],[1,3],[1,4] ...]

Tags: prolog

From a list [n, k], I want to return a set of all possible lists from 1 to k such that the length of all lists is n.

Example: the list `[2,4]` should return:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

Comment: I'm stuck, I haven't found à solution.

Comment: if you have an idea, do not hesitate to help me.

Comment: In what order do you expect the elements to be?

Answer (score 3):

```
n_k_lists(N, K, Ls) :-
   findall(L, ( length(L, N), maplist(between(1,K), L), ascending(L) ), Ls).

ascending([]).
ascending([E|Es]) :-
   ascending_(Es, E).

ascending_([], _E).
ascending_([E|Es], F) :-
   E > F,
   ascending_(Es, F).
```

That the elements should be ascending is just an indirect inference from your example. Using `library(clpfd)` this example would be much nicer.

( I am not a big fan of `findall/3`, but in this case here, it is fine.)

Comment: Yesss, You cannnn 'false' ;) Thank you 'false'

Comment: @Mraihi: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better understand how this site works. It's sometimes a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use finite domains, and @false's "ascending" predicate. In GNU Prolog, it would be:

```
nk_lists(N, K, Ls) :- findall(L, nk_list(N, K, L), Ls).

nk_list(N, K, L) :-
    length(L, N),
    fd_domain(L, 1, K),
    ascending(L),
    fd_labeling(L).

% @false's ascending...
ascending([]).
ascending([E|Es]) :-
   ascending_(Es, E).

ascending_([], _E).
ascending_([E|Es], F) :-
   E #> F,
   ascending_(Es, F).
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to transcribe this to SWI Prolog finite domain predicates if needed.

Comment: Just checked GNUs pl2wam: it recreates `[Y|T]`; thus needs lagging, too! And it leaves open a choicepoint! (For lists with one or more elements)

Comment: @false ah right. I should have stuck to your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code.  I am not sure it is very efficient, but it does the job.  To get the answers in list form you need to call `findall/3`

`findall(Z,list_combo([2,4],Z),X).`

```
list_combo([0,_],[]).
list_combo([X,Y],L) :-
    length(L,X),
    L=[A|As],
    n_ups(Y,Ints), &the numbers for our permutations
    member(A,Ints),
    not_member(As,A), &each element must be unique
    Length is X-1,
    list_combo([Length,Y],As),
    ordered(L). &must be in ascending order

n_ups(N, Xs) :-
   length(Xs, N),
   numbered_from(Xs, 1).

numbered_from([], _).
numbered_from([I0|Is], I0) :-
   I1 is I0+1,
   numbered_from(Is, I1).

not_member([], _).
not_member([N|Ns], M) :-
    dif(N, M),
    not_member(Ns, M).

ordered([_|[]]).
ordered([X,Y|Ys]) :- 
    ordered([Y|Ys]),
    X =< Y.
```

Comment: Thank you cxw, I will try to understand your code.  ;)

Comment: Hello False ;) ,  by writing  n_k_lists(2,4,L). , I found the result :    

L = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[3,4],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4]]        but I want to eliminate the duplications, for example for [1,3] and [3,1] it should return just [1,3].  and not have [1,1] , [2,2] , [3,3] ...